# How to show that the complex matrix $B + iC$ is unitary if I have the following information:

Tags: linear-algebra, unitary-matrices

I know that the matrix $D$ is a real orthogonal matrix.

$D = \begin{bmatrix}
B & -C\\
C & B
\end{bmatrix}$

That would mean that $DD^T = I => \begin{bmatrix}
B & -C\\
C & B
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
B & C\\
-C & B
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix} => B^2 + C^2 = I$ and $BC - CB = 0 => BC = CB$

How would I use this(if I even need it) to prove that $B + iC$ is unitary?

Comment: first think about scalar case, $b^2+c^2=1$, it means that $b$ and $c$ lie on unit circle. Now for the matrix case, eigenvalues of unitary matrices lie on unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

Your transpose is not right. From $DD^T=I$ you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B & -C\\
C & B
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
B^T & C^T\\
-C^T & B^T
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix} ;$$
combined with $D^TD=I$, you get
$$
BB^T+CC^T=B^TB+C^TC=I, \qquad BC^T-CB^T=C^TB-CB^T=0.$$
Now $$(B+iC)^*(B+iC)=(B^T-iC^T)(B+iC)=B^TB+C^TC+i(B^TC-C^TB)=I.$$ The computation for $(B+iC)(B+iC)^*$ is similar (and not needed since we are dealing with matrices).